# Add a random number between 30 and 300 to an existing field

Tags: sql, mysql, random, numbers

I have looked on the net as well as here but can't find an answer to the following MySQL question. I'm looking to replace the value of an existing field with a query that has a random number between 30 and 300.
Reason was because I've moved galleries and had 250,000,000 views on my images and there have been lost with the migration and a lot of my members are upset that they have lost views....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UPDATE the_table SET the_field = the_field + FLOOR(RAND() * (270 + 1)) + 30
```

Comment: Isn't a float casted to int when inserted into an INTEGER column?

Comment: But there was another problem in our both solutions: Half the probability for 30 and 270 than for the other numbers. I corrected it.

Comment: Thanks guys... I used this and it has saved my life :)

Answer (score 4):

Use [RAND()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)

```
UPDATE table

SET field = FLOOR(30 + (RAND() * 270));

WHERE foo = 'bar'
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this will do the trick:

```
UPDATE  table SET  field =  ROUND(30 + (RAND() * 270)) WHERE id =1;
```